# geolib for React - Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'getCenter' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

I keep getting this error when using geolib for React. I've imported geolib and getCenter both from geolib and it still isnt working. This is what im trying to do:

```
calculateMidpoint = (locations) => {
 geolib.getCenter(locations)
 .then(() => {
   debugger
 })
}
```

but I cant even reach my debugger because this error is thrown: 
"Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'getCenter' of undefined". I'm confused because I do import geolib, so what may my problem be?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: How do you import `geolib`?

Comment: import {geolib, getCenter} from 'geolib'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should import `geolib` next way:

```
import geolib from 'geolib';
```

and use it like this

```
geolib.getCenter(/* ... */)
```

or

```
import {getCenter} from 'geolib';

// ...
getCenter(/* ... */)
```

I think it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling "geolib" and install geolib again;

```
import getCenter from "geolib/es/getCenter";
```

and use it like this

```
getCenter(/* ... */)
```

It may solve your problem.